# Drive Realtime API typing for Drive docs?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to create an app that "types" into a text document in Drive. The goal is to have a document which is publicly viewable, if not editable, and a program which enters text into that document as though it were being typed by a person. If I use the following Drive API endpoint `PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/fileId`
will a viewer see the edits taking place a character at a time? (assuming I upload each version with one character difference). Or is there a function which would allow me to programmatically "type" each character?

My perusal of the Realtime API makes it look like this is what I want *except* that it involves setting up a separate page, where what I'm looking for is just the ability to write to a doc in Drive, in real time. Am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a background script that writes to a file, you probably don't need the realtime API.  This is more designed for multiple users making changes at the same time.

However, it may be possible to accomplish what you want using the import/export functionality.

Use [realtime.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get) to get the contents of the file as json.  Then use [realtime.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update) to post a modified version of the contents.  This will cause the diff of the get and the update to be applied to the realtime model.  Any active clients will see the changes come in as some new characters added to the document.